# What does irregular watering mean?

Tags: watering, terminology

I've heard a lot about plants doing poorly with irregular watering, but what does that really mean as some people have access to surface water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irregular watering is about letting plant to suffer dry and then overwatering, and again and again.

Tomatoes do no like it (but many fruits), because plant will suffer on dry, and heavy expand on overwatering, so you get wound on the skin fruits. These do no look like nice, and on tomatoes could give some storage problem. [You may see it also on cherry, plums, etc].

Other plants (sweet peppers) also have problems, and fruits badly, or just stop growing existing fruits.

If roots have constant water, or in any case, they will not have many dry interlaced with owerwatering, this should not be a problem.  Note: vegetables as annual plant, may not have deep roots to get constant water, and soil could not let water to infiltrate up.

Experiment. If you see wound on skin, or fruits that do no growth further (but you see new fruits), think about watering more regularly.

Comment: my watering system is the rise, and fall of surface water, but others may not be so lucky, thanks 